# Delete with Case/If Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
Table1
+-------+-----------+----------+
| EmpNo | FirstName | LastName |
+-------+-----------+----------+
|   123 | Bob       | Smith    |
|   456 | John      | Smith    |
|   789 | Bill      | Smith    |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to make a stored procedure to either delete the entire table or just one entry from the table based on a parameter passed in.

Something similar to

```
Delete from Table1
Case where @DeleteAll = 1
    Then where EmpNo is not null
Else where EmpNo = @employee
```

or

```
delete from Table1
If @DeleteAll = 1
    Then where EmpNo is not null
Else
    where EmpNo = @employee
select * from Table1
```

Comment: would emp info ever be null?

Comment: No, I'll deal with error handling on that later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Delete from Table1
where @DeleteAll = 1
   or EmpNo = @employee
```

Comment: This is a neat approach.  I'll leave my answer as an example of using `IF` but I like yours better.

Comment: Both this and Aaron's delete everything for me when testing in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Disregard, seems to be a quirk of SQL Fiddle. When I built a test table in my live environment, it behaved properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF @DeleteAll = 1
BEGIN
   DELETE 
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE EmpNo IS NOT NULL
END
ELSE
   DELETE
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE EmpNo = @employee
;
```